# Can I insert a large Excel sheet into Word so that it shrinks to fit the page?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007

I don't want to manually tweak font and table dimensions. Ideally the whole thing should scale to fit the page.

I'm using the 2007 version for both.

Comment: What shrinking exactly mean for you? Decrease font size? Paste as picture and zoom? Optimize column width? How "large" is it?

Comment: Ideally the entire content would be scaled down as a picture would, without the limitation of it being pixelated if someone zooms in or no longer editable in case we want to add notes during a meeting. It's just large enough that it will fit on a horizontal layout with zero margins but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Seems that setting bigger page size in Word would be the solution so you can keep text and don't need to waste time with decreasing font size. I'd you want to print, just save as pdf first than you can scale down easily.

Comment: What stopped you? Did you try? At most if it can't be scaled down beyond Word's capabilities, you will get horizontal/ vertical scroll bars in the excel area.

Comment: Can you screenshot an example of what that would look like? Is there some special paste option I should be using? Currently if I select the cells and copy+paste them into Word, it either overflows the document or gets deformed to fit the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The above shows an Excel File inserted within a Word file, (Insert - Text - Object - Create from File - browse from your HDD)

If you single click over the block, 8 anchor points will appear in the boundary and moving them will change the size of image.

[image]

However if you double click on the block, entire Excel file will open and there will be 8 anchor points, by moving which the part of file visible within word changes. It has to be column-width wise and row-height wise, you can display or hide part row/ part column.

Then double click outside the block or press escape and the block will remain in word in its new size.

Answer (score 1):

Try highlighting the cells containing the desired rows and columns and going to Word and right click Paste Special.

You may be able to default the Word Document to the Font you want.

This is not a perfect solution as you just want to paste the cells into word and have them look right.

From my experience you are better off working to make your Excel Document Printable by setting the Print Area etc and forget about using Word for more than few columns.